# How to wait for data to be fetched from cloud firestore and then return them in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to fetch some data from cloud firestore and then return that data in a map. The problem is that the system returns the value before it is fetched and the promise is pending. I tried many things but am not able to solve the issue. It would be great if someone could help me with this!

```
function homepage(formData) {
    var cfire = cfirebase.firestore().collection('Details').doc('dsadsadasdsadasdsdsdasd');

    const test = cfire.get().then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            Name = doc.data().dd.dn;
            vehical = doc.data().dd.vn;
            vehicalNumber = doc.data().dd.vno;
            console.log(Name, vehical, vehicalNumber);
        } else if (!doc.exists) {
            console.log("Detail does not exist");
            return Promise.reject(new Error('Detail does not exist'));
        } else {
            throw Promise.reject(new Error('Server error!'));
        }
    }).catch(e => {
        return false
    });
    return {
        tripID: {
            c: false,

            dd: {
                // Driver name 
                dn: Name,
                // Vehical name
                vn: vehical,
                // Vehical number
                vno: vehicalNumber,
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify as I am not able to see any map here in your code. Try to be more precise what's your desired output and what is current output. Share some screenshots as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your function returns the object before you fetch data from cloud firestore is because `cfirebase.firestore().collection(...).doc(...)` is asynchronous and it returns a `Promise`, so you have to wait for that `Promise` to resolve before you return the final object.

You should read up on `asynchronous programming` if you're not familiar with the concept:

- [Asynchronous Programming](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html)

I suggest you change your `homepage` function so that it returns a `Promise` or utilize `async/await` to wait for `cfire.get()` to resolve with some value before you `return` the final object.

**Option #1**

```js
function homepage(formData) {
  const cfire = cfirebase.firestore().collection(...).doc(...)

  return cfire.get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc) {
        throw new Error("Server error")
      }
      if (!doc.exists) {
        throw new Error("Details does not exist")
      }
      // ...
      return { Name, vehical, vehicalNumber }
    })
    .then(result => {
      // result => { Name, vehical, vehicalNumber }
      // ...
      return {
        tripId: {...}
      }
    })
}
// then
homepage(...)
  .then(result => {...})
  .catch(error => {...})
```

**Option #2**

*To use `async/await`, you have to have `Node.js 8.x` or higher.*

```js
async function homepage(formData) {
  try {
    const cfire = cfirebase.firestore().collection(...).doc(...)

    const doc = await cfire.get()

    if (!doc) {
      throw new Error("Server error")
    }

    if (!doc.exists) {
      throw new Error("Details does not exist")
    }

    // ...
    return {
      tripID: {...}
    }
  } catch(error) {
    throw error
  }
}
// then
homepage(...)
  .then(result => {...})
  .catch(error => {...})
```

Read more about `async/await`:

- [Async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of asynchronous nature of JS. 
Write you return statements within '.then' block.

```
function homepage(formData) {
     var cfire = cfirebase.firestore().collection('Details').doc('dsadsadasdsadasdsdsdasd');

  const test = cfire.get().then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        Name = doc.data().dd.dn;
        vehical = doc.data().dd.vn;
        vehicalNumber = doc.data().dd.vno;
        console.log(Name, vehical, vehicalNumber);
         return {
                 tripID: {
                    c: false,

                    dd: {
                       // Driver name 
                          dn: Name,
                         // Vehical name
                         vn: vehical,
                        // Vehical number
                        vno: vehicalNumber,
                    }
               }
           };
    } else if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log("Detail does not exist");
        return Promise.reject(new Error('Detail does not exist'));
    } else {
        throw Promise.reject(new Error('Server error!'));
    }
}).catch(e => {
    return false
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
function homepage(formData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var cfire = cfirebase.firestore().collection('Details').doc('dsadsadasdsadasdsdsdasd');
        var returnObj = {
            tripID: {
                c: false,
                dd: {
                    // Driver name 
                    dn: '',
                    // Vehical name
                    vn: '',
                    // Vehical number
                    vno: '',
                }
            }
        }

        const test = cfire.get().then(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                returnObj.tripID.dd.dn = doc.data().dd.dn;
                returnObj.tripID.dd.vn = doc.data().dd.vn;
                returnObj.tripID.dd.vno = doc.data().dd.vno;
                console.log('returnObj => ', returnObj);
                resolve(returnObj);
            } else if (!doc.exists) {
                console.log("Detail does not exist");
                reject('Detail does not exist');
            } else {
                reject('Server error!');
            }
        }).catch(e => {
            reject('Server error!');
        });
    });
}
```

and call the function like this

```
homepage().then((res) => {
    console.log('res => ', res);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
});
```